# CSS triangle (or curved square) shape not showing correctly

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to create a shape that looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, it's sort of a triangle shape, but can also be considered a curved square (that is off screen).

To create the shape, I've tried to utilise transparent borders. However, the borders do not appear transparent, which isn't showing the shape.

```css
.hero {
  background-color: #001d40;
  padding: 182px 0 100px 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.hero__gradient {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #20c0f5, #a38cff, #00c4ff, #20c0f5);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  -webkit-animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
  animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
  border-bottom: solid 30px transparent;
  border-top: solid 30px transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

@keyframes gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="hero">
  <div class="hero__gradient"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h1>Title</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

I have also tried increasing the border numbers (from `30px`) to `270px`, which is the distance from the bottom of the `div` to the point in the triangle. But, this doesn't work well responsively.

It seems like my `linear-gradient` occupies the area, instead of it being transparent?

Is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Two gradients can do it:

```css
.box {
  height: 250px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(120deg, blue 60%,#0000 0),
    radial-gradient(100% 100% at 0 130%,blue 99%,#0000 ),
    
    /* the main background */
    linear-gradient(-45deg, #20c0f5, #a38cff, #00c4ff, #20c0f5)
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: I see the approach, pretty neat tbh, didn't know you could do it this way. However, since all the gradients (for the BG and for the curve) are on one element, the keyframe animation wouldn't work (as if I add it to the main container, which is `.box` in your case, the entire section will animate). Can the same shape be achieved via 2 divs?

Comment: @Freddy you can apply the animation. You have 3 background layer so you need 3 background-size and 3 background-position where you move only the third one